# Strange constraint behaviour in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipageviewcontroller, nslayoutconstraint

In storyboard I have `UINavigationController` without navigation bar and with root view controller `UIPageViewController` that has 2 children: [LoginVC](http://take.ms/z2ioZ) and [ChoosePlaceVC](http://take.ms/rvR6M).

*MainPageVC* is a simple subclass of UIPageViewController where I just set

```
[self setViewControllers:@[loginVC] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
```

In Login ViewController I set constraint to top for logo image to 0 (distance of the logo to the top of the screen is 0). But when I see it the first time the [distance](http://take.ms/SBUOi) from status bar is 20, and only when I go to next VC in UIPageViewController  (weakSelf is a weak reference to custom UIPageViewController):

```
[weakSelf setViewControllers:@[choosePlaceVC] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
```

and then go back to login VC:

```
[weakSelf setViewControllers:@[loginVC] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        }];
```

the distance from logo to status bar [becomes 0](http://take.ms/1EIwi). When I repeat moving to next VC and going back, the distance stays = 0 (and that's the right distance)

**Why does it appear the first time with the distance = 20 ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long investigation I figured it out:

In Storyboard in Attributes inspector of UIPageViewController in Extend Edges I unchecked in the checkboxes Under Top Bars and Under Bottom Bars.

And now the strange behaviour of constraints in fixed (and I noticed that in this case I anyway have the offset from the top of view = 20 px, but in always constant. But if add the subview of main view with the size like the main view, and if I add all the elements to this subview, the distance to top = 0 px).